# Determine the probability that at least $70$ out of these $80$ random variables exceed zero.

Tags: probability, self-learning

> Assume that $X_1, X_2,\ldots X_{80}$ are independent and identically distributed with the same distribution as $X$ (hence $X_i \sim F(x)$ for all $i=1,\ldots,80$). Determine the probability
>   that at least 70 out of these 80 random variables exceed zero.
>
> Probability density function is: 
>   $f(x) = 1/20(x + 2)^3,\ −1 ≤ x ≤ 1.$

My plan would be to calculate $P(X > 0)$ for one $X$, and then use the Hypergeometric distribution. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The idea to first compute $P(X>0)$ is good, but I don't see what the hypergeometric distribution has to do with it.  I would expect to use the binomial distribution or maybe a normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: I looked at it, and it seems to me that binomial is indeed better. Thank you!